# ReactJS: Getting my Instagram feed

Tags: reactjs, instagram

I have done instagram feed with jquery and no problem. but...

I'm tring to get my own instagram feed to my reactjs webapp.

But havent seen it yet. Got one error like that:

Fetch API cannot load http://api.instagram.com/v1/users/*******. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Is there any good package for that or do you guys have working examples?

Thank you for Your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension that adds the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for you when there is an asynchronous call in the page that tries to access a different host than yours.

[Here is the link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Add it to chrome, activate it and it should normally work.

Comment: But now still I cant see any insta feed tryed this thinggy https://github.com/Opentrace/react-instagram-feed

in react console it gets the json stuff but some how it doesnt show...